# How to clean a table after values missing from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, join, bbpress

I was unsuccessful trying to migrate a bbPress 1.0 instalation to the new bbPress 2.0 plugin on my WordPress, which made quite a mess on my `wp_posts` table.

I solved that by deleting every posts who was carrying the values `topic` and `reply` to the `post_type` column, and that was good.

But now I noticed that the `wp_postmeta` seems affected by lots of entries refering to posts that I've deleted. Both tables have the `post_id` column.

The question is: which SQL command I use to delete the values on `wp_postmeta` referencing lines who aren't anymore on `wp_posts`? I know it's some kind of join that I should use but I don't see how it would be to look for something who is not there and delete it.

PS: And what's up with WordPress tables not keeping referential integrity? I'm pretty sure it's possible to delete something automatically from `wp_postmeta` when deleting something related on `wp_posts`. Oh well…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a general way to manually delete rows from table a that have no match in table b is:

```
DELETE FROM table_a WHERE some_id NOT IN (SELECT some_id FROM table_b);
```

this may not be the most efficient way to do a mass delete (joins could probably do it faster), but I usually prefer a subselect in cases like this, it is easier to understand and therefore reduces the FUBAR probability (you don't want to accidentally delete rows in table_b etc)

so in your case you could probably do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id NOT IN (SELECT post_id FROM wp_posts);
```

if you are sure, these are the rows you want to delete, replace SELECT * with DELETE:

```
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id NOT IN (SELECT post_id FROM wp_posts);
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked with a few modifications. Turns out that `wp_posts` have an `id` column instead of an `post_id` one. I added the `low_priority` to the delete command to keep it process friendly. It made an 17MB table a new 500KB one. :)

Answer (score -1):

> I know it's some kind of join that I should use but I don't see how it would be to look for something who is not there and delete it.

Yes, you want to use outer joins.

> PS: And what's up with WordPress tables not keeping referential integrity?

A lot of newer applications now use entity frameworks and don't explicitly enforce referential integrity, just relationships. Atlassian JIRA, for example, doesn't enforce referential integrity.